# CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE crash in destructor on assertion failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, cppunit

Relevant part of the code snippet. The above code snippet results in generating the following error in Win VC 8 compiler during exit. Making the assertion pass in destructor fixes the crash. This error is observed only in the windows and it works fine in linux.

```
class BasicMathTest: public TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(BasicMathTest);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testAdd);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testMultiply);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testDivide);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

    class A
    {
        public:
            ~A()
            {
                CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE( "BasicMath::Addition", 0 );
            }

    };

    A ob;

    public:
    virtual void setUp( void );
    virtual void tearDown( void );

    void testAdd( void );
    void testMultiply( void );
    void testDivide( void );

    private:
    BasicMath *obj;
};

int main()
{
   TestRunner testrunner;

   Test *tests = TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest();
   testrunner.addTest( tests );
   testrunner.run( m_testResult );
   m_outputter->write();
   return !m_collector.wasSuccessful();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor and the destructor of a TestFixture are not protected against exceptions. If you want to use assertions in this stage you'd need to change the code so you can move the code that uses assertions (throws an exception) into setUp/tearDown.

Actually it might not even terminate with an unhandled exception and instead crash because you might get a second exception while unwinding the stack. To separate the state for different tests the test fixture is wrapped into a functor and each test gets a new instance that is stored in a vector. This hows once more that it is nearly always a bad idea to throw an exception in a destructor.